# Документация по C++

Tags: c++

Начал изучать C++. Смотрю и читаю уроки, пока все понятно. Хотелось бы почитать документацию официальную. Нашел только официальный сайт и то на англ. Искал сайт на русском не нашел. Подскажите может кто знает ? или вообще нету документации по C++ на русском :(

Comment: Вам не хочется читать официальную спецификацию языка, поверьте мне. Почитайте лучше Страуструпа. Видеоуроки не смотрите.

Comment: @VladD, может человек компилятор писать собрался. Или статический анализатор :-)

Comment: @klopp: Хм, вы правы. Ладно, тогда видеоуроки разрешаем :-D

Comment: @VladD, Или так: "Спецификацию языка официальную не хочется, поверьте мне, читать Вам!" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Джесс Либерти - C++ Энциклопедия пользователя"

У него же есть хорошая книжка (только не смейтесь) "Джесс Либерти - Освой самостоятельно С++ за 21 день". В свое время по ней изучал с нуля.

Еще можно Страуструпа посмотреть.

Comment: Насчёт "21 дня" -- это к Норвигу.

Answer (score 2):

Тут ещё вот что имеет значение: **какой именно** C++ изучается. Например, в MSDN, [всё на русском](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3bstk3k5.aspx) (но от настоящего C++ это, мягко говоря, может отличаться):

> В этом справочнике описывается язык
> программирования С++ **в том виде, в
> котором он реализован в Microsoft
> Visual C++**. Справочник создан на
> основе аннотированного справочного
> руководства по C++ Маргарет Эллис
> (Margaret Ellis) и Бьорна Страуструп
> (Bjarne Stroustrup) и международного
> стандарта ANSI/ISO C++ (ISO/IEC FDIS
> 14882). Включены реализации
> компонентов языка С++ корпорацией
> Майкрософт.

Но какие-то вещи там есть, а уточнить можно и на нормальных сайтах на английском, если захочется вылезти за пределы Visual Studio.

Comment: @klopp "настоящий C++"? Помнится, до первой версии стандарта была первая редакция Страуструпа и вторая... И какой же C++ настоящий?

Comment: @alexlz, ну, криво выразился. Имелось в виду, что там описывается майкрософтовская реализация C++, а не стандарт в чистом виде.